# not in sodoers: boot into single user mode from mint18 live disc

Tags: ubuntu, 32-bit

I can't really say what happened, it seems it was all working good (ubuntu server 20.04, apache, mysql, a dockered wikijs..) I've been able do many sudo operation after installing the machine.
Now, for some reason, when I try to sodo, it seems that I'm not in sodoers.

As described
I can't (or simply I don't know how to do it) get single user mode work (to get root access and assign my user to sodoers again).

So I'm in a loop: can't sudo, can't boot into single user mode.

Can anybody suggest me how to boot into single user mode, booting from a mint 18 installation disc?